# My Convert_to_Hex function in C modifies previously converted variables

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, hex

I have three char arrays each filled with 32 chars. I'm trying to convert each of them to HEX and store them in a 64 byte char array. The first char array, ai_values_temp get converted normally and when I print it out (ai_values_hex_temp), it prints the correct 64 bytes of HEX. However, when I convert the second char array, bi_values_temp, and then print ai_values_hex_temp, it prints out the previous 64 bytes + the 64 bytes of bi_values_hex_temp. I was wondering if anyone would be willing to look into my code.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <GMPMessage.txt> <GMPSeed.txt>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int gmpMessageLen;
    unsigned char *message = Read_File(argv[1], &gmpMessageLen);

    int seedLen;
    unsigned char *seed = Read_File(argv[2], &seedLen);

    int n = gmpMessageLen / 32;

    unsigned char *prnData = PRNG(seed, seedLen, 2 * n * 32);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        unsigned char ai_values_temp[32];
        unsigned char bi_values_temp[32];
        unsigned char mi_values_temp[32];

        char ai_values_hex_temp[64];
        char bi_values_hex_temp[64];
        char mi_values_hex_temp[64];

        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
        {
            ai_values_temp[j] = prnData[i * 64 + j];
            bi_values_temp[j] = prnData[i * 64 + 32 + j];
            mi_values_temp[j] = message[i * 32 + j];
        }
        char ai_values_hex_copy[64];

        Convert_to_Hex(ai_values_hex_temp, ai_values_temp, 32);
        printf("Ai value %d %s\n",i,  ai_values_hex_temp); // normal
        Convert_to_Hex(bi_values_hex_temp, bi_values_temp, 32);
        printf("Bi value %s\n", bi_values_hex_temp);
        printf("Ai value %d %s\n",i,  ai_values_hex_temp); // normal + bi_values_hex_temp
     }
     return 0;

void Convert_to_Hex (char output[], unsigned char input[], int inputlength)
{
    memset(output, 0, 2 * inputlength + 1);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < inputlength ; i++) {
        sprintf(&output[2*i], "%02x", input[i]);
    }
    //printf("Hex format: %s\n", output);
}
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: You're not allocating space for the `\0` character that terminates your strings. You need `char ai_values_hex_temp[64 + 1];` etc.

Comment: Gives me `realloc(): invalid old size. Aborted (core dumped)` error.